# my python discord bot which is supposed to download a youtube video does not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to programming, I am trying to create a python discord bot on replit which downloads youtube videos because I wanted to download memes and the websites online are very sketchy.

I made it have 2 commands: ping and video. the ping command works fine but when I do the video command I get this error in the console:

```
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://youtube.com/shorts/beXDaeCqEq8?feature=share
[youtube] beXDaeCqEq8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] beXDaeCqEq8: Downloading android player API JSON
[info] beXDaeCqEq8: Downloading 1 format(s): 315+251
[download] video.mp4.webm has already been downloaded
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --prefix=/nix/store/7x62j0rls5dpriig91qrk0qh7hvvqd7k-ffmpeg-4.4.1 --arch=x86_64 --target_os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-pic --enable-libsrt --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-os2threads --enable-network --enable-pixelutils --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-avcodec --enable-avdevice --enable-avfilter --enable-avformat --enable-avresample --enable-avutil --enable-postproc --enable-swresample --enable-swscale --disable-doc --enable-libass --enable-bzlib --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libssh --enable-vaapi --enable-libdrm --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-lzma --disable-opengl --disable-libmfx --disable-libaom --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libx265 --enable-libdav1d --disable-debug --enable-optimizations --disable-extra-warnings --disable-stripping
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
video.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Here is my repl: https://replit.com/@Lets-GoGo7/PYVS

and heres the code in main.py

```
import os
import discord
import yt_dlp
import subprocess
from webserver import keep_alive
import ffmpeg

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('sv video '):
        url = message.content.split(' ')[2]
        ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': 'video.mp4'}
        try:
            # Delete previous video if it exists
            if os.path.exists('video.mp4'):
                os.remove('video.mp4')

            with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])

            # Compress the video using FFmpeg
            crf = 28
            while True:
                cmd = f'ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf {crf} -preset slow -acodec copy compressed_video.mp4'
                subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

                # Check file size of compressed video and send it if it is less than 8MB
                if os.path.exists('compressed_video.mp4'):
                    file_size = os.path.getsize('compressed_video.mp4')
                    if file_size <= 8000000:
                        with open('compressed_video.mp4', 'rb') as f:
                            await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(f))
                        break  # Exit the loop if the file size is less than 8MB
                    else:
                        # If the compressed file is still too large, lower the CRF value and try again
                        crf -= 2
                        if crf <= 20:
                            await message.channel.send('The compressed video file is too large to upload.')
                            break
                        else:
                            os.remove('compressed_video.mp4')
                            continue  # Try again with a lower CRF value
                else:
                    await message.channel.send('Error compressing the video file.')
                    break

            # Delete the compressed video file
            if os.path.exists('compressed_video.mp4'):
                os.remove('compressed_video.mp4')

        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(f'Error downloading, compressing or sending video: {e}')

    elif message.content == 'sv ping':
        try:
            await message.channel.send(f'Pong! Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send(f'Error sending ping message: {e}')

keep_alive()
```

Please help me, thank you in advance.

I wanted it to download and send the video on discord but it just gives me the error given above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I noticed you're downloading a webm file yet you're looking for a mp4 file.

Comment: @ewokx thanks, yeah I am trying to download a mp4 file but idk why it downloads a webm file

Comment: `yt-dlp` downloads as webm, so you have to convert it to an mp4 manually afterwards. Also, don't abuse replit to host Discord bots.

Comment: Please use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRobin sorry I am new